# can't use roscd to find package?

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First ,I create a workspace ,then create a package ,and things all go right . Then I creat my second package in the same workspace ,and  catkin_make ,but I can't roscd the second packgage! I can roscd the first package!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254813/can%27t--use-roscd-to-find-package?/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've just `catkin_make`d your workspace with your second package:

- make sure to `source /path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` again (you'll have to do this after every package addition / removal)
- run `rospack profile` to force an update of the package cache that `roscd` uses

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-02-16**:
thanks , since I source the devel/setup.bash ,the problem has been solved !

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-06-22**:
Hello, Thanks this answer was helpful, I just have a small doubt, is it possible to directly add a sourcing line to my bashrc file ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:\

> is it possible to directly add a sourcing line to my bashrc file ?

yes, but as you can read in my answer:

> you'll have to [source] after every package addition / removal

so unless you `source` your `.bashrc` again after adding or removing packages, it still won't work.

And at that point you're `source`ing either the `devel/setup.bash` or your `.bashrc`, which is the exact same amount of commands.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-06-22**:
Thank you, this helps